# Как реализовать маркеры сети организации при помощи Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошую статью по теме реализации маркеров на Google-картах для сети предприятия.

Как пример желаемого - http://podorozhnyk.com/#pharmacy_map.

Comment: Что вас конкретно интересует? Отобразить просто маркеры на карте, или объединять/разделять маркеры в зависимости от высоты?

Comment: Да, при зуме группировать, поиск и т.п. Полный аналог приведенного выше примера.